# how to user tensorflow MNIST mode for inference

Tags: tensorflow, mnist, inference

I am learning tensorflow. After completed the tensorflow tutorial MNist for expert (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros), I am trying to use the trained model to run inference. I copied two [28x28] images and put them into a [28x28x2] array and saved a matlab file. Then I used the following code to run inference:

```
data = sio.loadmat("data/test/testdig.mat")
data = tf.reshape(data["testdig"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1]);

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

....CNN network stuff

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

prediction = tf.argmax(y_conv, 1)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "model/mnist.ckpt") //restored the saved model
    print(prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: data, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

However, the code above gave me an error at the last line:

raise TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. '
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
data = tf.reshape(data["testdig"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

This means data is a tensor to be computed at some later time. You can't use this as an input since you don't know the value.

You either need to apply the reshape on `x` (your place holder) so that it happens in the model,

or use numpy operations to reshape the data to match what tensorflow expectes.